# Problema en count php mysql, funciona en phpmyadmin y no en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo esta función que me debería traer la cuenta de los registros de mi base de datos en mi página:

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id){
    $pendientes = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion FROM ticket as t JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id ") or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    return $consulta;
}
```

Hago la consulta en el phpmyadmin con la siguiente linea de código:

> SELECT COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion FROM ticket as t JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, cuando lo intento mostrar en mi página llamándolo:

```
<?php
    $resultadoss = $ticket->cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id);
    if($resultadoss > 0) // validamos si es mayor a 0
    {
        echo '<div id="notificacion">',$resultadoss,'</div> '; 
    } else {
        echo 'GG';
    }
?>
```

Aparece el GG que no debería .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser el error?

Luego del código de Ernesto:

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id){
    $pendientes = mysqli_query($conexion, 
                "SELECT COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, 
                 t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as
                 t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                 FROM ticket  as t JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id ") 
                or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

     $consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pendientes);

    return $consulta['contador_tickets'];
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendré que tener cuidado con los errores ortográficos ...

Volviendo al asunto.

Cuando uso el siguiente código queriendome traer todos los tickets que sean de mi mismo id no me retorna ningun valor.

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id){
    $pendientes = mysqli_query($conexion, 
                "SELECT COUNT(*) as contador_tickets FROM ticket  as t WHERE t.id_usuario = '$id' ") 
                or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

     $consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pendientes);

    return $consulta['contador_tickets'];
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta un ";" al final de la linea de la consulta

Comment: @LombardaArda No hace falta `;` en la línea de la consulta porque tiene un `or die(...);` después.

Comment: ¿En qué parte de la función `cuentaticketspendienteempleado()` llenas `$consulta`? Ya que esa es la variable que estás retornando...

Comment: Vista ya la acertada respuesta que te dio @ErnestoRM, parece que tu consulta trae datos que en tu función no estás necesitando: si sólo quieres saber la "cantidad", con el `COUNT()` te basta. El resto es gasto de memoria para el procesador...

Comment: @quinqui necesito contar la union de 2 cosas que estan en una misma fila.
Los tickets que sean creados por mi y sean de mi departamento.
La cuenta anterior solo cuenta los tickets creados. pero me muestra las notificaciones de los creados por otros.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que estas devolviendo una variable que no usas dentro de la función.
Prueba así:

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id){
    $pendientes = mysqli_query($conexion, 
                "SELECT COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, 
                 t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as
                 t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                 FROM ticket  as t JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id ") 
                or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

     $consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pendientes);

    return $consulta['contador_tickets'];
    }
```

**EDITO**

Si lo que quieres es consultar los tikets que se corresponden con el `id` que le pasas a la función ¿es necesario el `JOIN`? ¿no sería suficiente con un `WHERE`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as contador_tickets FROM ticket  as t WHERE t.id_usuario = '$id'
```

Comment: ese codigo me trae todos los tickets bro. no solos los creados por mi.

Comment: disculpa, tu bien  , respondiste la pregunta, mi problema es otro ahora. voy a darte el visto bueno y esperar , si puedes, a que me ayudes con la proxima (y)

Comment: @JuanOrtiz he editado la respuesta, a ver si te sirve.

Comment: si, es lo que quiero hacer, sin embargo , el problema es que no me trae los resultados , mostrandome el GG en la busqueda.
deberia almenos decirme que hay 1 , estoy en lo correcto? @ErnestoRM

Comment: editare la pregunta para que lo veas

Comment: Dices que no devuelve nada la consulta, añade esta línea `echo mysqli_error($conexion);` después del `mysqli_query()` a ver qué error te devuelve.

Comment: No es un error, simplemente no lo cuenta. 
en la imagen te muestra el "GG" que deberia mostrar si no hay elementos en la busqueda bro.

Comment: La variable `$id` que recibe la función tiene un valor asignado ¿no?